# What is the difference between accordion and show/hide

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have recently started a new project where I would like to show and hide information based on a user's click.  In the past I have always jumped right in and used the jQuery accordion plugin for this.  However as I learn more about Javascript in general I've started playing around with the show/hide function.  I am curious as to what is the difference between the two.  My guess is the jQuery accordion is a lot more flexible when it comes to different options but I was unable to find any information about this.

Comment: Accordion is just a fancy show/hide with an animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#default) is one of many widgets offered by [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/). It is useful when you have multiple content panels and want to display them in the same page/container. It also allows you to make your panels collapsible.

On the other hand, jQuery show/hide are just basic functions that the Accordion Widget *utilizes* - [Accordion source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/accordion.js).

So you are right about Accordion having more options than simply showing/hiding content (Sortable, fill space, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The show/hide functions simply do just that.  They show or hide an element by setting their visibility to hidden and their display to none.